The easiest way to lengthen the lifespan of mattresses
Consider two people with non-identical body shape and density, Alice and Bob. Alice and Bob move in together and need to purchase a bed to sleep on; in accordance to custom in Northern Europe, they purchase two single-size mattresses and put them next to each other to create a sleeping surface with the same width as a single king-size bed.
It is recommended by the mattress salesperson to regularly – i.e. every three months or so – rotate, flip, and swap the mattresses in order to maximize their lifespan. Alice and Bob decide that they want to maximize the time between either one of them returns to the same mattress in the exact same state. At the same time, Alice and Bob want to achieve this goal with the least amount of mental energy as possible, so the instructions should be as simple as possible.
In other words, consider a set $S = \mathbb{B}^5$ representing whether the mattresses have been swapped, whether Alice's mattress has been flipped, whether Alice's mattress has been rotated, whether Bob's mattress has been flipped, and whether Bob's mattress has been rotated. Every three months, Alice and Bob can decide to flip and/or rotate either of the mattresses and to swap them. This, similarly, gives a group action $\alpha$ over $G = \mathbb{B}^5$ s.t.:
\begin{equation}
\alpha(g:G, s:S) = \begin{cases}
(\neg s_0, s_3 \oplus g_3, s_4 \oplus g_4, s_1 \oplus g_1, s_2 \oplus g_2)& \text{if}\;g_0\\
(s_0, s_1 \oplus g_1, s_2 \oplus g_2, s_3 \oplus g_3, s_4 \oplus g_4)& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Alice and Bob want to come up with an element $g$ in $G$ which maximizes the time before either of them sleeps on the same mattress in the same configuration. An exhaustive computer search reveals that the maximum cycle length achievable over the naive definition of $G$ gives a cycle length of four using $\hat{g}$; given that there are 32 total states, this is far from the maximum. Since any iterative composition of elements of $G$ is definitionally also in $G$, Alice and Bob find that eight elements of $G$ which compose into $\hat{g}$ are enough to obtain the full 32-length cycle, but this imposes upon them an eight-step rotation cycle which spans two years.
Alice and Bob now wish to improve on this (somewhat unsatisfactory) result. They are looking for ways to improve on either the cycle length achieved using a single action, i.e. to find a cycle length greater than 4, or to find a shorter series of actions which gives a long cycle length (it need not be exactly 32), i.e. to find a cycle with length less than eight. They can change their definition of $\alpha$ or $G$ freely, or even approach the problem from an entirely different angle. Is there any way they can do better?

Is it really $32$? I find it hard to parse the setup of this problem, but I think you're asking about the symmetry group of the pair of mattresses $G$, and looking for (1) the element of largest order, and (2) the smallest generating set. Is that correct? If so, the group has 128 elements (8 symmetries of each mattress, and the swap).

Oh I see, the mattresses are not squares but rectangle, so it is a group of order $32$.

The symmetry group you're talking about can be written $(A\times B)\rtimes S$, where $A$ is the symmetry group for Alice, and is elementary Abelian of order $4$; similarly for $B$. $S$ is the swapping action, of order $2$. So this is a group of order $32$. The maximal order of an element in this group is $4$, matching what is in the question body.
The group is generated by three elements, namely the elements generating $A$ and $S$. But that's not helpful if you want to have a repeated list of things to do (e.g., "first flip, then rotate, then swap"). Because then we're still asking for the order of an element that is the product of generators, and that cannot be more than $4$. So "time to return to start" / "length of list" is capped by $4$.
Things get more interesting if the list doesn't have to be cyclic, such as "this time Alice does the task, next time Bob does". For example, if my math is right, if the list is "rotate/flip/swap", and we alternate Alice and Bob, I think this gives $20$ of the $32$ positions.
